# Regex to have two out of three character types

Tags: regex

I want to test a string which may consist of three types of characters:

1.Alphabetic letters (uppercase or lowercase)
2.Numbers
3.Special characters (non-alphanumeric characters)

I want to test if the string contains any two out of the three above character types (and no less than 8 characters) with regex, right now I have the following regex

```
^(?=.*0-9)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9]).{8,}$
```

However it seems this tests if the string contains each of all three character types, not any two out of the three.

BTW I'm looking for a pure regex solution, I know this check can be done easily with something like the following

```
types = 0;
if contains numbers then types++;
if contains alphabetic letters then types++;
if contains non-alphanumeric letters then types++;
if types >= 2 then pass; else fail;
```

However I'm just wondering if this can be accomplished by a single line of regex.

Comment: I think `(?=.*0-9)` should be `(?=.*[0-9])` using a character class.

Comment: yup it's a typo, my bad.